# Jackson does not find a property of a POJO in a Micronaut application compiled to a native image

Tags: java, jackson, micronaut, graalvm-native-image

I've created a simple application with Micronaut 2.0.0: it was generated using Micronaut application generator here https://micronaut.io/launch/ , and then I added the following:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @Get("/hello")
    public Result hello() {
        return new Result("Hello world!");
    }
}

public class Result {
    private final String message;

    public Result(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then I build the application using `./mvnw clean package`.

When I start it with `java -jar target/micronaut-minimal-1.0.jar`, it successfully starts. It responds correctly:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello
{"message":"Hello world!"}
```

Now I build a native image:

```
native-image -jar target/micronaut-minimal-0.1.jar target/app
```

Then I run it:

```
target/app
```

It starts OK.

And now the same request produces an error:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello
{"message":"Internal Server Error: Error encoding object [com.example.Result@7f21a9858b70] to JSON: No serializer found for class com.example.Result and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"}
```

I tried adding `@JsonProperty` to the `message` field or `getMessage()` method (with or without `value` attribute), to no avail.

I believe that has something to do with the fact that reflection is probably not available in a native image. But how do I solve this issue?

I'm using GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02) for both running and building the jar and image.

Comment: The GraalVM native-image compiler does some heavy optimization at compile-time. Among other things, it may delete unused fields and/or methods. The compiler does, however, not see all reflective accesses, thus it may delete fields or methods that are invoked reflectively. To prevent this from happening, one can instruct the compiler to not optimize (certain parts of) certain classes. See [this page (section "Manual Configuration")](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/REFLECTION.md) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 ways to solve the problem: one specific and cleaner, another is more universal but dirtier.

## @Introspected annotation

The cleaner way is very simple: just annotate the class with `@Introspected`:

```
@Introspected
public class Result {
    private final String message;

    public Result(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

That's it. If I understand correctly, this annotation makes Micronaut generate introspection classes at compile time which are then probably used by Jackson serialization machinery. The documentation says that

> You can enable bean introspection integration with Jackson for reflection-free JSON serialization and deserialization using the jackson.bean-introspection-module setting.

but in my case it just worked.

## Reflection configuration

As noted by @Turing85, as `Result#message` and `Result#getMessage()` are not referenced in the code, `native-image` has no idea that we still need them at runtime, so no trace of them is left for Reflection API (which is probably used by Jackson by default).

We can instruct the `native-image` tool to keep this information. First, we need to create a JSON configuration (in my case, the file is called `reflect-config.json`):

```
[
  {
    "name" : "com.example.Result",
    "fields" : [
      { "name" : "message" }
    ],
    "methods" : [
      { "name" : "getMessage", "parameterTypes" : [] }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here we instruct the tool to keep field `message` and method `getMessage()`.

Then we supply this file using `-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles`:

```
native-image --no-server -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json -jar target/micronaut-minimal-0.1.jar target/app
```

More information: https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/REFLECTION.md

## Approaches comparison

The first approach is cleaner because it totally avoids the usage of reflection (which means the code works faster and consumes less memory).

The second approach is still more universal because the first approach is only possible if specifically handled. If a tool still requires reflection, you have no choice but sticking with it.

Comment: with Micronaut, you could also use the @TypeHint annotation

Answer (score -1):

Just add @JsonSerialize to your pojo class.

```
@JsonSerialize
public class Result {
    private final String message;

    public Result(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```